# Python: docoptで複数の引数を一つのオプションで取得したい

Tags: python

Pythonの引数解析に`docopt`を使おうと思ったのですが、思うように取得できません。

```py
from docopt import docopt

__doc__ = """{f}
Usage:
    {f} [[-w | --word-list] <word_list>...] [[-d | --data-list] <data_list>...]
""".format(f=__file__)


def main():
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    print(args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

これを実行すると、期待通りにはデータが入ってくれません。

```
$ python option_test.py --word-list word1 word2 --data-list data1 data2
{'--data-list': True,
 '--word-list': True,
 '-d': False,
 '-w': False,
 '<data_list>': [],
 '<word_list>': ['word1', 'word2', 'data1', 'data2']}
```

期待する動きとしては`data_list`には`data`が、`word_list`には`word`が入って欲しいのですが･･･

```
こうなって欲しい
$ python option_test.py --word-list word1 word2 --data-list data1 data2
{'--data-list': True,
 '--word-list': True,
 '-d': False,
 '-w': False,
 '<data_list>': ['data1', 'data2'],
 '<word_list>': ['word1', 'word2']}
```

上記のようなオプション指定はそもそも不可能なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

上記のオプションではできそうにないようですので、カンマ区切りまたはスペース区切りで一つの変数として渡し、その後`split`することにしました。

```py
from docopt import docopt

__doc__ = """{f}
Usage:
    {f} [-w <word_list>] [-d <data_list>]

Options:
    -w --word-list <word_list>  Setting words.
    -d --data-list <data_list>  Setting datas.
""".format(f=__file__)


def main():
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    print(args)
    word_list = args['--word-list'].split(',') # スペース区切りの場合は' '
    print(word_list)
    data_list = args['--data-list'].split(',') # スペース区切りの場合は' '
    print(data_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

実行結果

```
$ python option_test.py --word-list word1,word2 --data-list data1,data2
{'--data-list': 'data1,data2',
 '--word-list': 'word1,word2'}
['word1', 'word2']
['data1', 'data2']
```

スペース区切りの場合

```
$ python option_test.py --word-list "word1 word2" --data-list "data1 data2"
{'--data-list': 'data1 data2',
 '--word-list': 'word1 word2'}
['word1', 'word2']
['data1', 'data2']
```

Comment: `<word_list> Setting` の部分、区切りのスペースは２つ以上必要です。

Comment: [Option descriptions](http://docopt.org/) での _Use two spaces to separate options with their informal description._

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ご指摘ありがとうございます。修正しました。

Answer (score 2):

どうも質問で書かれているようにして期待するようにはできないみたいですね。
でも、

```
Usage:
    {f} [-w <word_list>...] [-d <data_list>...]

Options:
  -w --word-list <word_list>...   Word List.
  -d --data-list <data_list>...   Data List.
```

の様にして

```
-w word1 -w word2 --data-list data1 -d data2
```

（長いオプションでも短いオプションでも同じオプションを意味する）
の様に引数を渡すと

```
{'--data-list': ['data1', 'data2'],
 '--word-list': ['word1', 'word2']}
```

の結果が得られます。

Comment: この渡し方はちょっと厳しいですね。。やっぱりできなさそうですね。というかOptionsの方にエイリアス書けば良いんですか！

Comment: 通常の書き方だけだとオプションの引数というのが表現できないようですね。それで、オプションの引数は`--opt value` or `--opt=value` を想定していると思われます。オプションの引数が指定されていない場合は単にオプションフラグと引数(つまり`'-d':true`のような意味になる),
既に自分で回答されているように`,`でつないで１つの値としてリストを渡す（あとでsplit)はできます。

Answer (score 1):

オプションパラメータの個数を固定してもよいのであれば、以下の様に書けます(パラメータは2個)。

```
{f} [-w WORD WORD|--word-list WORD WORD] [-d DATA DATA|--data-list DATA DATA]
```

実行結果です。

```
$ python option_test.py --word-list word1 word2 --data-list data1 data2
{'--data-list': True,
 '--word-list': True,
 '-d': False,
 '-w': False,
 'DATA': ['data1', 'data2'],
 'WORD': ['word1', 'word2']}
```

最初は以下の様に書けるのではないかと思ったのですが、

```
{f} [[-w|--word-list] WORD WORD] [[-d|--data-list] DATA DATA]
```

`--data-list` だけを指定すると結果がおかしくなってしまいます。

```
$ python option_test.py --data-list 3 4
{'--data-list': True,
 '--word-list': False,
 '-d': False,
 '-w': False,
 'DATA': [],
 'WORD': ['3', '4']}
```

Comment: 可変長の引数としたいので、固定はしたくないのです･･･